# Send input to command line using AutoIt

Tags: input, command-line, exe, executable, autoit

I am new to autoit and am trying to automate the input to an .exe program. This executable does not have a gui and is run from the command window so can I use autoit to send the program specific input through the command window? If so how can I go about doing this?

```
Local $engine= "C:\Users\Davis\Desktop\Chess engine\stockfish32bit.exe"
Local $PID = RunWait(@ComSpec & " /k " & $engine, "", "@SW_MAXIMIZE")
;Insert code that sends program "uci" as input
```

Comment: Have you tried coding the sending of the 'uci' as input?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the syntax and capabilities of autoit so I was hoping that someone here would know how to code this.

Comment: Have a look at `ControlSend` function - http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm . This is used to send strings of text to the window. Have a try and post results :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I added a ControlSend function along with a pause in the script to allow the application to open and it works perfectly.

Comment: Great, glad to help! You can post your code (solution) in an answer, so that anyone else looking for a similar problem and solution can find it.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790266/4157124).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple example shows how you can communicate with previously ran program.

```
; Demonstrates the use of StdinWrite()
#include <Constants.au3>

Local $foo = Run("sort.exe", @SystemDir, @SW_HIDE, $STDIN_CHILD + $STDOUT_CHILD)
; Write string to be sorted to child sort.exe's STDIN
StdinWrite($foo, "rat" & @CRLF & "cat" & @CRLF & "bat" & @CRLF)
; Calling with no 2nd arg closes stream
StdinWrite($foo)

; Read from child's STDOUT and show
Local $data
While True
    $data &= StdoutRead($foo)
    If @error Then ExitLoop
    Sleep(25)
WEnd
MsgBox(0, "Debug", $data)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Local $engine= "C:\Users\Davis\Desktop\Chess engine\stockfish32bit.exe"
Local $PID = RunWait(@ComSpec & " /k " & $engine, "", "@SW_MAXIMIZE")
$hCmd=WinGetHandle($engine)
ControlSend($hCmd, "", "", "uci" & @CR)
```